# Why reading a value from Label in Ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I'm trying to read a value from a Label(asp) with Ajax.
but i'm allways get Undefind :|

My Code is:

```
function NIS2USD() {
    var from = document.getElementById("NIS").value;
    var to = document.getElementById("USD").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("totalAmountLabel").value;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = ProcessResponse;
    request.open("GET", "Convert.aspx?from=" + num1 + "&to=" + num2 + "&amount=" +    amount, true);
    request.send();
}
function USD2NIS() {
    var from = document.getElementById("USD").value;
    var to = document.getElementById("NIS").value;
    var amount = document.getElementById("totalAmountLabel").value;
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = ProcessResponse;
    request.open("GET", "Convert.aspx?from=" + num1 + "&to=" + num2 +  "&amount="+amount, true);
    request.send();
}
function ProcessResponse() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("totalAmountLabel").innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
}
```

and My def for the label is:

```
<asp:Label ID="totalAmountLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Why I'm always getting undef?

Comment: oh dear god global `request` variable.

Comment: View the page source in the browser/fiddler and see why. :)

Comment: I don't foolow sorry! I'm very new in asp and Ajax so I don't know what are you talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the client ID for the label.

```
var amount = document.getElementById("<%=totalAmountLabel.ClientID%>").innerHTML;
```

Comment: 10x! Working! Why I need to use this syntax? what this syntax means?

Comment: Because for accessing the server control in javascript you have to work on the client id (id that is rendered in the browser) which is different from server control id. And the above code, is used to get the client id of the server control.

Answer (score 1):

it is because controls get renamed when inside an update panel.
try to use this if you have jQuery reference

```
$('#<%=totalAmountLabel.ClientID%>')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `<asp:Label>` is generating an HTML `<label>` tag.  If so, it doesn't have a `.value` attribute.  Try `.innerHTML` instead.

```
var amount = document.getElementById("totalAmountLabel").value;
```

should be

```
var amount = document.getElementById("totalAmountLabel").innerHTML;
```

Comment: `<asp:Label>` only renders as label when the AssociatedControLID is set; otherwise, it renders as span.

Comment: @BrianMains: I don't actually know ASP, but either way you want `.innerHTML` not `.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the javascript to (the javascript code must be defined in page for this to work, not in a JS file because of the `<%= %>`):

```
 document.getElementById("<%= totalAmountLabel.ClientID %>").innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Or leave the javascript as is and change the label to (for 4.0):

```
<asp:Label ID="totalAmountLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:Label>
```

Client ID mode of static ensures on the client the ID is actually totalAmountLabel